# Prove that the transformation $S$ and its powers, $S^n$, is not injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ - Linear space.

$T$ - Linear transformation:

$$
T:V \to V
$$

$(1)$ Prove that $\forall k \in \Bbb N, k \geq 1$:

$$
\ker T \subseteq \ker T^2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \ker T^k \subseteq \ker T^{k+1} \subseteq\cdots
$$

$(2)$ Prove that if $V$ has finite dimension, so $\exists m, \ker T^m = \ker T^{m+1}$

$(3)$ $S$ - linear transformation: $S:R^4 \to R^4$ satisfies: 
$$
S(x,y,z,t) = (x-y+t, x-z, y-2z,2x-2z)
$$
Does $\exists n \in N$ such that $S^n$ is injective?

---

In order to be injective we would like that:

$$
\ker S = \{0\}
$$

Therefore, for the system $Sx = 0$ we will have nly the trivial solution: the zero vector.

We will represent $S$ as a matrix:

$$
[S]_E = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&1 \\ 1&0&-1&0 \\ 0&1&-2&0 \\ 2&0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
[S]_Ex = 0: \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&1&|0 \\ 1&0&-1&0&|0 \\ 0&1&-2&0&|0 \\ 2&0&-2&0&|0 \end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{RREF} \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&1&|0 \\ 0&1&-2&0&|0 \\ 0&0&1&0&|0 \\ 0&0&0&0&|0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

So we got infinite number of solution with dim([S]_E) = 1.

And by question 1 we can conclude that $\forall n \in N: \dim(\ker S^n) > \dim(\ker S) = 1$

Therefore, the kernel never contains only the zero vector therefore the tranformation is never injective $\forall s^n, n \in N$.

Any correction? ideas for a better way to solve?

Comment: A minor correction: the strict inequality $>$ should be a $\geq$ (for example plug in $n = 1$).

Comment: Right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a non-injective endofunction on any set, then it is easy to see that no positive power of $f$ can be injective either. Hence, it suffices to show that $S$ fails to be injective, or equivalently, that it kills some nonzero vector. An example of a nonzero vector killed by $S$ is the vector $(1,2,1,1)$. In fact, the kernel of $S$ is $\{(t,2t,t,t):t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.